# Ruby and databases

Tags: ruby, wordpress

I am new in programming in Ruby, not to mention databases, so i would like a few pointers to my question. I have a few websites, where i gather information from users by a form, which they fill out (my websites are in Wordpress). The form is made in Contact Form 7 (https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) and the info is stored in the database with this plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/).

My question is: Is it possible to make a ruby program, that would fetch info from my sites (databases) and show me the information? Is there a better way of doing this (Ruby on rails perhaps)?

Comment: Are your databases different? What I mean, your wordpress database differs from your ruby website?

Comment: What do you want to display and in what way? Just a table? Do you want to create a file? Or do you want to show the data in the page itself? If so, you should get familiar with wordpress, and Ruby won't help you much... But for the other options Ruby will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to access your wp data from a ruby app. You will need to familiarise yourself with the [wordpress api](http://v2.wp-api.org/). This [gem](https://github.com/robmiller/ruby-wpdb) might also help. You can build a small sinatra based app to keep it simple or use rails.

Comment: Great! Thanks, I will check it out!